# A small question regarding typing congruences

Tags: formatting

I have a trouble generally in making space while typing using LaTeX;
I will give a quick example about where my problem is;
i type `a\equivb (mod p)` and when put it in signs `$a\equivb (mod p)$`
There is no space between `mod` and `p` and possibly the brackets and `b` how can I fix that, or is there a specific command for modulo that i don't know.

Thank you:)

Comment: `$a \equiv b \pmod{p} $`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Do you want to write up an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$a \equiv b \pmod{p} $
```

produces the ... (mod p) form, there is also `\bmod` for the  infix `a \bmod p` form producing *a* mod *p*